# Qt: How to make window icon bigger (SVG)?

Tags: qt, svg, icons, gnome

I'm using Qt 4.8.1, and set the window icon with:

> app.setWindowIcon(QIcon("/path/to/icon.svg"));

However, no matter how big the svg icon is, the icon shown in the menu bar or when using "alt-tab" in gnome is always very low resolution and "pixelized".

How can I make it render the icon in a higher resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this can be only avoided when providing a desktop menu entry with a high a resolution icon.

I downloaded qtcreator to test it: When running the version from the web, the icon is bad. As soon as the installed version is run, it works, because the icon from the menu is used.

Comment: I run into the same issue; I have a PyQt4 window where the icon was specified in QtDesigner, and the same icon loaded via `setWindowIcon` in c++ in another window. The one from the designer and in python is not pixelized with alt-tab, while the one (loading the same `.svg` file into QIcon) is badly pixelized.